# How to handle back button using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security and i was wondering how to solve this back button or problem of the browsers.

The thing is that after i login , when i click the back button . I am coming to the login page again. It would be very good if even on clicking the back button you stay in the logged in home page only.

Same must be if i am logged out it should not be like when i click the back button i am again in the logged in home page. I am not sure what to do to solve this. I know browser caches the pages but When i use standard website like facebook or yahoo , looks like there is already some solution for it. Any direction or info will be very helpful.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of you problem comes from browser cache. You can disable it in multiple ways:

- Configure Spring MVC interceptor for all your pages:

```xml
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**/*"/>
            <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
                <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
                <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
                <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
                <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

- Call response methods:

```java
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

- Add meta tags to corresponding pages:

```html
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
```

Comment: but when u do back and forth no request is send to the server...so how this helps...

Comment: It forces browser to do request instead of using local cache

Comment: No, even like that: this forces browser to do not stock this page in the cache. So when you hit back button browser can show you a page only by doing one more request.

Comment: I mean i inlcuded it in as meta tags...I did back and forth and no request was sent to the server. ...is i need to do something more...

Comment: To make it work you need to force your browser to reload this page at least once. Hit Ctrl+F5 on this page and try again.

Comment: Have you tried another way? Response.setHeader or interceptor?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the built-in [cache control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-cache-control) of Spring Security:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
      // ...
      .headers()
         .defaultsDisabled()
         .cacheControl();
   }
}
```