# redirecting to login page once user logs out and then presses browser back button with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, filter

I am using Spring Security. Once the user logs out, and then he presses back button on the browser, the last page shows up. Now of course when the user tries to do some operation on the page, he is redirected to the login page. But the requirement is that he should not be able to even see any page in of the application unless he is logged in.

I have implemented this facility in another web app by using filters. But since spring security works on the fundamentals of filters itself, so I think there should be a way to achieve this feature without using separate custom filter.

Comment: This can be your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147302/how-to-handle-back-button-using-spring-security

Comment: That shows how to force browser to do the work. Is it not possible to handle using spring security?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of spring security are you using? Are you using the `<headers><cache-control /></headers>` config?

You want the following to force refresh on back button:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the browser not to display `cached` page on the click of `back button`, you need to `disable cache`. By default Spring Security does not inject cache headers.
This can be easily achieved by following this configuration inside your `spring-securityConfig.xml` (something similar) file.
I am assuming that you are using xml configuration, hence you can set

```
<security:http ........>
   <security:headers>
      <security:cache-control />
    </security:headers>
</security:http>
```

Please note, you may get into a new problem after doing the above configuration changes. You would notice that this header makes the browser to request `.js` and `.css` or `static resources` every time you load a new page. This will hamper the performance, and you want these static contents to be cached. In such scenario you need to `configure` spring security to apply `configuration` on `static contents` as below:

```
<!-- Static content, must be declare before your form login config -->
<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
```

Assumption here is your `static contents` are in `resources`.

Please feel free to comment out in case of any issue!